# Making brackets around a function larger

Tags: brackets

In my project I want to define e as a limit and have the following

```
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} {(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}$$
```

but the brackets don't line up properly, the curved brackets don't go around the entire fraction and look messy. How do I correct this?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remember `$$...$$` is not recommended under LaTeX, it does not comply to LaTeX configurations, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: @AntRobinson It is required (or strongly recommended) to provide typesetable code so that your problem can be easily reproduced by everybody else. Since you're new on the block, I'll let this one slide ;)

Comment: How do I do that? So I know for the future.

Comment: @AntRobinson You should just wrap it with minimal code. Add a document class and the relevant commands and environments. For example `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}my problem\end{document}` Then all anybody has to do is copy and paste your code and try running it to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh you mean like this:

```
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} {\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n} $$
```

[image]

The key points in the code

- `\left(`
- `\right)`

Comment: That's it!! Thank you so much, I shall accept your answer as soon as it will let me.

Answer (score 5):

A slight improvement for the exponent placement:

```
\[ \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!\! n} \]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use `\big`-like constructs. The advantage is that you do not have `\left` `\right` problems in case your equation is splitted across several lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to\infty} {\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to\infty} \bigg( 1+\frac{1}{n} \bigg)^n
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to\infty} ( \big( \Big( \bigg( \Bigg( 1+\frac{1}{n} \Bigg)^n
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]